# Not able to Access Elasticsearch node from remote hosted on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to access Elasticsearch node hosted on free tier of AWS.
I have opened the port in security group for all IP as well. 
It works fine on local.

`curl: (7)Failed to connect to **ip-to-ec2** port 9200: Connection refused.`

ElasticSearch version 2.1

Comment: Can you post your `curl` command?

Comment: curl http://52.77.214.167:9200

Comment: Are you sure that is an external and not internal IP? Sure you have.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by default elasticsearch binds locally. So to configure that we have to configure elasticsearch.yml

---

just put network.host to 0.0.0.0 for access from all host/ip

> Be careful as anyone use as we don't have any authentication on
>   elasticsearch node. Try to keep specific.

Answer (score 0):

add the following line in config\elasticsearch.yml (u can use vim to edit the file)

host.host: 0.0.0.0

Note : elasticsearch version 6.1.3